# How to move a CCSprite inside CCNode In cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a Bird which is a (CCSprite) and i want it to be flying in the Top of screen off course, So i add CCNode and add the bird as child on it but it's still flying outside of the CCNode!

MY CODE IS:

```
@implementation GamePlay {

    CCSprite *myBird;
    CCNode *theFlyingArea;
}

-(id)init {

    if(self=[super init]) {

       theFlyingArea = [CCNodeColor nodeWithColor:[CCColor colorWithRed:0.2f green:0.2f blue:0.2f alpha:0.4f] width:viewSize.width height:viewSize.height*60/100];
       theFlyingArea.position = ccp(0, 0);
       theFlyingArea.positionType = CCPositionTypeMake(CCPositionUnitPoints, CCPositionUnitPoints, CCPositionReferenceCornerTopLeft);
       theFlyingArea.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 1);
       [self addChild:theFlyingArea z:1];

       float RandomY = arc4random() % (int)theFlyingArea.contentSize.height;

       // Create MY BIRD
       myBird = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"myBird.png"];
       myBird.scale = myBird.scale / 2;
       myBird.position = ccp(-10, RandomY);
       [theFlyingArea addChild:myBird z:2];       

    }

    return self;
}

- (void)update:(CCTime)delta {

   id moveTo = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:100.f position:ccp(((float)rand() / RAND_MAX) * theFlyingArea.contentSize.width , ((float)rand() / RAND_MAX) * theFlyingArea.contentSize.height)];

   [myBird runAction:moveTo];
}

@end
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you expect the sprite's position to be limited to the size of the CCNodeColor? That's not going to happen automatically. You either need to use physics to create a screen-sized edge and a polygon shaped physicsBody for the bird, or in update: verify that the moveTo position isn't outside the screen/color node by clamping the position to the desired extents.